# Patchwork not aligning x axis with ggbreak

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I was able to use patchwork to align two xaxis, but when I add ggbreak::scale_**break(), it no longer aligns. What am I doing wrong here? Code of alignment issues follows. UnComment out scale**_break() lines to see difference.

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbreak)
library(patchwork)

y <- as_tibble(c(rnorm(400,100,25),250) )
n= nrow(y)
cor = n/100
a.mean = mean(y$value)
a.median= quantile(y$value,0.5)
a.sd = sd(y$value)
binwidth = 5
upper.limit <-  260

plt1 <-ggplot(y, aes(x="", y = value) ) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "lightblue", color = "black", outlier.shape=NA) +
  stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar',coef=NULL) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=7.6, color="black", fill = "blue")  +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(color="black", fill = NA, size = 1),
        axis.text = element_text(size=14)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Value ($)") +
  #scale_y_break(c(200,240 ) ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty(c(0,upper.limit), n=10), limits=c(0,upper.limit) ) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x.top=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x.top=element_blank() )

plt2 <- ggplot(y, aes(x = value) ) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)*100 ),
                 position = "identity", binwidth = 5,
                 fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x)
    dnorm(x, mean = a.mean, sd = a.sd) * n * binwidth / cor,
    color="darkblue", size =1) +
  ylab("Percentage") +
  xlab("") +
  #scale_x_break(c(200,240 ) ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty(c(0,upper.limit), n=10), limits=c(0,upper.limit) ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,15, by=2.5)) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(color="black", fill = NA, size = 1),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        text=element_text(size=20),
        axis.text = element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x.top=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x.top=element_blank() )

Fig01_01 <- plt2 / plt1 + plot_layout(nrow = 2, heights = c(10, 2) )
Fig01_01
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the solution is but I think the problem is that `ggbreak` adds a class ("ggbreak") to the ggplot object so it prints it differently. `patchwork` on the other hand is looking out for `ggplot` objects and can do some clever tricks to line up axes. Encountering a `ggbreak` object it doesn't recognise it and try interpret it and instead prints as is (no padding to left of lower graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to manually/invisibly add in the y-axis labels and ticks for the bottom plot as exactly the same size as the upper plot. `ggbreak` does additionally seem to add in an immovable margin around the whole plotting area, so you may have some extra white space between plots doing it this way:

```r
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbreak)
library(patchwork)

y <- as_tibble(c(rnorm(400,100,25),250) )
n= nrow(y)
cor = n/100
a.mean = mean(y$value)
a.median= quantile(y$value,0.5)
a.sd = sd(y$value)
binwidth = 5
upper.limit <-  260

plt1 <-ggplot(y, aes(x=1, y = value) ) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "lightblue", color = "black", outlier.shape=NA) +
  stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar',coef=NULL) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=7.6, color="black", fill = "blue")  +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(color="black", fill = NA, size = 1),
        axis.text = element_text(size=14)) +
  xlab(" ") +
  ylab("Value ($)") +
  scale_y_break(c(200,240 ) ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty(c(0,upper.limit), n=10), limits=c(0,upper.limit) ) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(colour = "white", size = 14),
        axis.ticks.y=element_line(colour = "white"),
        axis.text.x.top=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=20),
        axis.ticks.x.top=element_blank() )

plt2 <- ggplot(y, aes(x = value) ) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)*100 ),
                 position = "identity", binwidth = 5,
                 fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x)
    dnorm(x, mean = a.mean, sd = a.sd) * n * binwidth / cor,
    color="darkblue", size =1) +
  ylab("Percentage") +
  xlab("") +
  scale_x_break(c(200,240 ) ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty(c(0,upper.limit), n=10), limits=c(0,upper.limit) ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,15, by=2.5)) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(color="black", fill = NA, size = 1),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        text=element_text(size=20),
        axis.text = element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x.top=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x.top=element_blank() )

Fig01_01 <- plt2 / plt1 + plot_layout(nrow = 2, heights = c(6, 2) )
Fig01_01
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried that trick and it is closer, but I could not get it to line up. There was some X axis shifting to the left that remained on the bottom plot.

Comment: It may be that some elements are missing then - try printing the `xlab`, `axis.text.y` and `axis.ticks.y` of `plt1` in black to see if they match the size of the upper plot. In my example above it's using the same-sized text and ticks to push the lower plot in a little at the left.

Comment: You're right, they do seem to line up. The key is adding all the elements, ticks, text, labels. Thank you!